# What happens to CSE-relative resourceIDs in attributes of announced resources?

Tags: onem2m

Let's say an MN-CSE announces an `areaNwkInfo` to an IN-CSE. The `areaNwkInfoAnnc` resource in the IN-CSE has a `listOfDevices` attribute that contains a list of MN-CSE-relative `resourceID`s.

Is that correct? If so, what use are those `resourceID`s in the IN-CSE? How, for example would one map those `resourceID`s to announced `areaNwkDeviceInfoAnnc`s ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not correct. The MN-CSE (as originator of the announced resource request) should set any resource identifier reference to the correct format (as per TS-0001 clause 7.2, latest paragraphs). In your case, SP-relative.

In addition, if I am not wrong, areaNwkInfo resource cannot be announced as per TS-0001 Annex D.5, table D.5-2.

Comment: [areaNwkInfo] is a specialisation of <mgmtObj>, which can be announced. See also TS-0001, Table 9.6.18-1: Child resources of <node> resource

Comment: "TS-0001 clause 7.2, latest paragraphs", can you please clarify which paragraph you mean?

Comment: It seems that some attributes are missing for areaNwkInfo in table D.5-2. 

Paragraph I was referring to is the following (in particular the first sentence): 
"The format (i.e. CSE-relative, SP-relative or absolute) of resource identifier (e.g. the To parameter, accessControlPolicyIDs attribute) shall be correctly set by the Originator in an initial request, while the format of AE-ID or CSE-ID in the From parameter shall be set in a shortest format by the Originator in the initial request and it shall be converted in another format by the Registrar CSE or IN-CSE as the following."

Comment: Ok, that sentence could really use some copy-editing. It's not clear what "correctly set" means, or what "a shortest format" means.

Does this imply that even though Table 9.6.1.3.1-1 states that `resourceID` is 'Unstructured-CSE-relative-Resource-ID', when a `resourceID` is referenced in another attribute (eg. `listOfDevices`) and sent to another CSE, then the format should be converted to `SP-relative` ? If that's the case you guys really need to call that out, because it's really not clear from the text.

Comment: .. and does this imply that all such attributes should be translated in both upsteam & downstream requests between CSE-relative & SP-relative formats? If so, this is IMO a huge requirement that's way too important to be hidden behind such a vague specification here.

Comment: is there a list of these magically translated attributes anywhere? i note that the type of `listOfDevies` is `m2m:listOfURIs`. it would be helpful (for codegen) if there were `m2m:resourceID` and `m2m:listOfResourceIDs` types in the xsd that indicated where these translations were necessary.

Comment: Well, the paragraph I copied should be read together with the rest of the clause. "Correctly set" means that it depends in the context (within a CSE, another CSE, etc..) the identidiers are going to be used. "Shortest" means Unstructure CSE-Relative, any other format will be longer. The table 9.6.1.3.1-1 is talking about the resourceID attribute which is specific for every resource. When announcing a resource, the announced resource will get its own resource identifier, that's why that specific attribute uses always Unstructured CSE-Relative.

Comment: Other attributes (like listOfDevices) should use the appropriate format to reference to other resources depending on the context. I think you have had a good idea to mark attributes that need to be format translated when need to be used in a different context (different CSE or Service Provider). I will open a discussion for that.